# To prove the inequality of two positive variables

Tags: inequality, optimization

$m$, $n$ are natural numbers.
$a$, $b$ are positive numbers such that $~a^{m}=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ , $~b^{n}=\dfrac{1}{m+1}$

prove that $~a+b\geq 1~$ **without calculus**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma:**
Bernoulli inequality:

$$(1+x)^a\le 1+ax,0<a<1,x>-1$$

and your problem is  use  Bernoulli inequality
$$a+b=\dfrac{1}{(m+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{m}}}>\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{m}{n}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{n}{m}}=1$$

**By the way :**

we  use  Bernoulli inequality  have this 
well konw inequality 
$$x^y+y^x>1$$
for any $x,y>0$

Comment: Maybe include the Bernoulli proof of $x^y+y^x>1$ so it's clear no calc needed.